# How do I add a shortcut to refresh current page in firefox and keep the focus on current window?

Tags: shortcut-keys, automation

I'm doing web development and for that reason I need to refresh some page in firefox frequently (it's on another display, so I see both IDE and browser at the same time). At the moment I manually use the mouse to set focus to firefox, refresh it, and then put the focus back to IDE.

How can I add a keyboard shortcut that would make the currently active tab of a visible browser refresh the page, with focus staying where it currently is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a xdotool-based shell script for that.

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Then write a simple script like this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

WID=`xdotool search --name "Mozilla Firefox" | head -1`
xdotool key --window $WID F5
```

Name it and place it as you wish. Make it executable:

```
chmod a+x /path/to/script
```

Now you can simply make a custom keyboard shortcut that will execute the script and you are all set up.

Comment: This works, also you can have it in one command: `xdotool search --name "Mozilla Firefox" key "F5"`

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Auto Reload](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-reload/). It's an add-on for Firefox that automatically reloads the page when a particular local file is modified.

Comment: I tried one of those, but I'd need to set a small refresh interval, and when something goes wrong I need to disable autorefresh which is even more hassle than refreshing manually.